# Angular4 tabs not working using <mat-tab-group>

Tags: angular

Can't get tabs by using `<mat-tab-group>`

I have installed latest nodejs, angular cli, and angular material
but i cant get tabs when i run project in browser

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
node: 8.7.0
os: linux x64
@angular/animations: 4.4.5
@angular/cdk: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/common: 4.4.5
@angular/compiler: 4.4.5
@angular/core: 4.4.5
@angular/forms: 4.4.5
@angular/http: 4.4.5
@angular/material: 2.0.0-beta.12
@angular/platform-browser: 4.4.5
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.4.5
@angular/router: 4.4.5
@angular/cli: 1.4.5
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.4.5
@angular/language-service: 4.4.5
typescript: 2.3.4
```

Registration component Html

```
<app-header>


</app-header>

<div class="mainwrap">
        <div class="heading"> 
        Registration
        </div>

        <mat-tab-group>
            <mat-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>


</div>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
    [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'registration',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
    path: 'registration',
    component: RegistrationComponent
    }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: what error you getting in console ?

Comment: have you included css file ?

Comment: no error in console.. successfully compiled..
i think there is no need for css as per documentation @Rahul

Comment: check for css file then !

Comment: you need to add material theme.

Comment: i have installed angular material..
as you can check in details of angular i provided

Comment: add `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` in your style.scss

Comment: still not working

Comment: can you check if tabs related DOm bing rendered in browser by inspecting it? can you check if above css file does exist ?

Comment: above css file exists.. loaded in browser,,
but has not given any rules yet

Comment: strange...check out this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vuvaem? link? I have simulated the material tabs

Comment: check all the moduls in above link and css in style.css .. thats all you have to do

Comment: i think its same..

Comment: @RajatGupta there must be some another issue .. or **CSS** issue. include above css in style.css only not in component level

Comment: yes i have added in style.css and according to angular documentation css is not necessary to display tabs

Comment: according to https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme  **Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application.**

Comment: i think css is not required for using **material components**
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview
they have not mention to use css

however i have used as per you

Comment: @RajatGupta does that solves ur issue ?? Can you anyhow replicate ur issue on stackblitz ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have found my answer after some research

I did not `import BrowserAniminationModule` in `app.module.ts` due to which i could not use the tabs properly.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. All the required imports are present. Code gets compiled. I do see a mat-group element in my DOM but I am not able to see any tabs that I added.

Comment: Have you also inported the css?

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem similar only with mat-tabs, and it appears it was another error that was causing trouble.
After resolving other issues (in browser console), the tabs finally appeared !

Comment: True... in my case I had an interpolation in HTML inside Mat-Tab failing causing Tabs not to show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

***Include theme***

https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-4-include-a-theme

Including a theme is required to apply all of the core and theme styles to your application.

To get started with a prebuilt theme, include one of Angular Material's prebuilt themes globally in your application. If you're using the Angular CLI, you can add this to your styles.css:

@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

If you are not using the Angular CLI, you can include a prebuilt theme via a  element in your index.html.